# How to solve"Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector:cache_removals is already in use by anotherCollector of typeMicrometerCollector"

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus

How to solve " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: cache_removals is already in use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector" with springboot 2.6.6

stack

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: cache_removals is already in use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: cache_removals is already in use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: cache_removals is already in use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector
at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.register(CollectorRegistry.java:57)
at io.prometheus.client.Collector.register(Collector.java:308)
at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$applyToCollector$16(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:479)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use the springboot 2.6.6 version and because of this error I can't the max I can do is use the 2.4.13 version but the latter does not correct the Spring4Shell security flaw

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue

```
**Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: reactor_netty_connection_provider_total_connections is already in use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: reactor_netty_connection_provider_total_connections is already in use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector**
```

So, Error was because, there were two beans getting created of **PrometheusMeterRegistry**, first was due to dependency of **spring-boot-starter-actuator-autoconfigure** and other i was specifically creating by `new PrometheusMeterRegistry()`. So, both of them were trying to register the same metrics. Hence it was causing the issue.

So, I removed the bean of prometheus registry, which i was creating explicitly and that solved my problem.